# How to convert this mips code to C?

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I am asked to convert this mips code to c. I really worked very hard and ran this code on the Qtspim simulator. But I don't figure out how to convert to C ?

The initial address of source array (b) is stored in $a1, and the initial address of destination array (a) is stored in $a0. The length of the array is stored in $a2 register.

```
      li $t0,0
      beq $a2,$0,skip
loop: lw $t1,0($a1)
      bgt $t0,2,else
      lw $t2,-8($a0)
      lw $t3,-4($a0)
      addu $t2, $t2,$t3
      addu $t1,$t2,$t1
else: sw $t1,0($a0)
      addiu $a0,$a0,4
      addiu $a1,$a1,4
      addiu $t0,$t0,1
      bne $t0,$a2,loop
skip:
```

What I don't understand are

```
lw $t2, -8($a0)
```

and

```
lw $t2, -4($a0)
```

In array structure, we know A[-2] or A[-1] is wrong. Then, how does that work ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Write the code down in C in a way that's exactly like the asm code. Line by line, as much as possible. It's perfectly valid to do `A[-1]` etc when you're *in the middle* of the array. `A` in this case isn't the beginning of the array, it points somewhere further in the array. Think like `char B[10]; char* A = &B[2];` in this case `A[-1]` is completely valid.

Comment: As I understand, pointers must be used in this case, mustn't they ? @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: Yes, since you can only have a fixed offset in the code you must move the pointer around in MIPS asm and can't just index into an array like in C.

Comment: Thank you kindly. @SamiKuhmonen